# Is there linux tools to deal with Windows Client Certificate Enrollment Protocol?

Tags: linux, windows, active-directory, certificate, csr

I'm using Linux in corporate network with Active Directory (through samba). I generated CSR, using openssl and whant to enroll it with ActiveDirectory's autoenrollment. Is there any linux tools for it, or I need to deal with windows' nftive tools?

WCCE: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc249879.aspx